# How does meteor application uses packages?

Tags: meteor

How does meteor application uses packages? 
For eg. I have "twbs_bootstrap" in meteor packages directory but still bootstrap css is not being applied to the components in HTML templates. Sorry if the question seems very basic as I have just started learning meteor.

Comment: Show your code. And is bootstrap listed when you do `meteor list` in terminal?

Comment: Where is the twbs_bootstrap folder from? If you install packages with e.g. `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` it shouldn't appear in `/packages` but would be somewhere in `/.meteor/local`.

Answer (score 0):

Run `meteor add twbs:bootstrap`. If it'a already installed you will get something like `twbs:bootstrap without a version constraint has already been added.` If not then it will add it for you

From there all you need to do is add the bootstrap class names to your elements to get it to work.

You can do a quick test by creating a new app, added twbs:bootstrap, and then just adding a `btn btn-primary` class to the button on the demo
`<button class="btn btn-primary">Click Me</button>`

If all is working you will get a blue button.